# ¿Cómo cambiar el valor de una variable php desde la base de datos mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysqli

Estoy programando un carrito de la compra con `php` y `mysqli`. Tengo una variable fija llamada: `$iva = 12;` en el archivo **cart.php**.

Con la variable (iva) obtengo el impuesto de los productos añadidos a la cesta.

Pero ahora trabajando en el panel de control (**cms**), Necesito cambiar el valor de la variable `$iva = 12;` desde la base de datos. Para así poder administrar las configuraciones del carrito de la compra desde el panel de control.

Es decir si yo tengo una base de datos llamada `cart` en la cual tengo la siguiente estructura de la base de dato:

`id    iva
 1     18`

Entonces como cambiar el valor de la variable `$iva = 12;` al valor del registro de la base de datos que es 18, `$iva = 18;`.

En resumen necesito mostrar el valor del **IVA** desde la base de datos.

Cómo se realiza la consulta a la base de datos para cambiar el valor de una variable???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vayamos por partes.

- Conexión a la Base de Datos ([documentación W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp)) con formato: `mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);`

  ```
  <?php
      $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

      // Check connection
      if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
  ?>
  ```
- Consultas a la Base de Datos (con la conexión otra vez y adaptado a tu caso) ([Dcoumentación W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp))

  ```
  <?php

      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "username";
      $password = "password";
      $dbname = "myDB";

      // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } 

      $sql = "SELECT id, iva FROM cart";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          // output data of each row
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - IVA: " . $row["iva"]. "<br>";
              $iva = $row["iva"];
          }
      } else {
          echo "0 results";
      }
      $conn->close();

  ?>
  ```

Para obtener el dato que necesitas en lugar de `echo` asígnalo cómo necesites.

- Actualizar valores de la Base de Datos (con la conexión otra vez y adaptado a tu caso) ([documentación W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp))

  ```
      <?php
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "username";
      $password = "password";
      $dbname = "myDB";

      // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } 

      $sql = "UPDATE cart SET iva='18'";

      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
          echo "Record updated successfully";
      } else {
          echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
      }

      $conn->close();
      ?>
  ```

Comment: Perfecto amigo te lo agradezco mucho, sabia que la consulta debería ser diferente a una consulta normal gracias.

Comment: Tengo una pregunta planteada en ingles de como duplicar una sesión de un producto al añadir un color o talla diferente si puedes me puedes ayudar o chequearla [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010678/how-duplicating-a-session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010678/how-duplicating-a-session) Saludos, Nuevamente muchas gracias.

Comment: @J.Doe Podrías publicarla también aquí traducida :)

Comment: vale amigo ya esta publicada :)  [http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20938/c%C3%B3mo-duplicar-una-sesi%C3%B3n](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20938/c%C3%B3mo-duplicar-una-sesi%C3%B3n)

Answer (score 1):

Deberías empezar por verte la documentación de mysqli [aquí](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp).

En primer lugar tienes que hacer una conexión con tu bd mediante `mysqli_connect()`, para mas adelante mediante `mysqli_query()` lanzar una consulta y recorrerla con algún método tipo `fetch`.

Comment: Creo que el OP está preguntando cómo *modificar* los valores de la Base de Datos, no sólo obtenerlos. Y la mayoría de lo que comentas creo que debería ir en un comentario.

Comment: "Entonces como cambiar el valor de la variable $iva = 12; al valor del registro de la base de datos que es 18, $iva = 18;.

En resumen necesito mostrar el valor del IVA desde la base de datos." Por eso entiendo que quiere hacer una consulta y quiere cambiar el valor de una variable que utiliza.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo :) Pero al final añade: `Cómo se realiza la consulta a la base de datos para cambiar el valor de una variable???`

Comment: @JoseFG Amigo en la respuesta publicada es una consulta normal como cualquier registro a mostrar. Lo que yo necesito es cambiar la variable fija  `$iva = 12;` desde una consulta a la base de datos así poder cambiar el valor de la variable a `$iva = 18;` u otro valor.

Comment: @MiquelColl Exactamente si necesito amigo una consulta, pero una consulta para cambiar el valor de la variable, porque en una consulta normal y mostrar los datos `echo` este dato se mostraría en la pagina web, lo que realmente necesito es cambiar el valor de la variable no mostrar el resultado en la pagina web.

Comment: @J.Doe mira mi respuesta. Ahora te modifico el echo para hacer asignación pero ya lo tienes